# TIMER1 to measure the delay accurracy in avr atmega328p?

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

```
unsigned long slptime=0;
unsigned long wdttime_count = 0;


void timer1_init()
{
    //TCNT1=0xFF4E;//16ms
    TCNT1=0xFFF5;//1ms
    // TCNT1=0xFF9B; //10ms
    TIMSK1=0x01;
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM10); // RV09_H, Date: 05-May-2022, set Normal mode operation
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM11);
    TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM13);
    TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM12);
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12) | (1<<CS10); //1024 prescalar; fosc=11059200hz; freq=fosc/1024 = 10800hz; t=0.092ms;
}

void timer1_stop()
{
    TCCR1B = 0x00;
    TIMSK1 = 0x00;
}
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    //TCNT1=0xFF4E;//16ms
    TCNT1=0xFFF5;
    //TCNT1=0xFF9B;
    wdttime_count=wdttime_count+1;
}

void main()
{
    timer1_init();
    _delay_ms(250);
    timer1_stop();
    sendtimediff((wdttime_count*1000)/1080);
}
```

The timer1 is configured for 1080Hz by counting upto 10 at 10800hz. I was just checking the timer accuracy but the above code return 227ms instead of 250ms.

What I am missing in it? Or _delay_ms() is causing the error?

Comment: Is TCNT1 a free running timer that wraps around? Or a down counter which triggers at zero? Or something else? How is it cleared, or is it never cleared?

Comment: TCNT1 is configured for nomral operation. It is incremented and overflow after 0xffff to 0x0000.  @Lundin

Comment: If you start the counter at 0xFFF5 and count up until a rollover then isn't it counting to 11 instead of 10?  250 * 10 / 11 = 227

Comment: kkrambo has solved your problem, but I'll just add: modifying the timer count in an ISR is suspect, and likely to lead to some small inaccuracy.  It would be much better to configure the timer's period by setting its "TOP" value, so refer to the datasheeto learn how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

1. When you set timer value to `0xFFF5` it increments 11 times before the overflow.

*11059200 / 1024 / 11 =  981,8 Hz == **1,0185 ms.***

It counts 245 times.

*245 * 1000 / 1080 = **227***

You probably want to set value to `0xFFF6`

2. There is no need to set the timer in each interrupt. Instead, you can use CTC mode, forcing the timer to count from zero to a value in `OCR1A` *(Mode 4)* or `ICR1` *(Mode 12)*. E.g.:

```
void timer1_init()
{
    TCNT1=0;
    OCR1A = 9; // from 0 to 9 == 10 timer (prescaled) clock cycles

    TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A); // Use Output Compare interrupt
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM10); // Set Mode 4 (CTC)
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM11);
    TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM13);
    TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM12);
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12) | (1<<CS10); //1024 prescalar; fosc=11059200hz; freq=fosc/1024 = 10800hz; t=0.092ms;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) // use Output Compare A vector, instead of Overflow
{
    // No need to reset the timer
    wdttime_count=wdttime_count+1;
}

...
```

3. Keep in mind that `_delay_ms` macro just counts CPU cycles, therefore if there are interrupts happened during the delay, the delay can take longer time. `_delay_ms` and `_delay_us` macros are generating plain CPU loop, which counts with accuracy up to single CPU clock cycle, but only when the loop itself is not interrupted.
4. There is no point to compare `_delay_ms` to timer clocked from the same main clock, as the CPU itself. The comparison result will be always the same, no matter what actual CPU speed is.

Answer (score 0):

Classic bug for free running timers, `TCNT1=interval;` in the ISR won't work. It needs to be something like:

```
volatile uint16_t next_TCNT1 = TCNT1;
next_TCNT1 += interval;
TCNT1 = next_TCNT1;
```

The reason for this is: you have set the interrupt to trigger when the timer compare hits a certain value. That's the point when the timer flag is set, but from the point where that happens until you reach the actual code inside the ISR, a lot of time has passed, *interrupt latency*. This was particularly nasty on the various old, crap architecture 8-bitters.

So by the time you update the timer counter, it isn't sitting at "interval", but rather at "interval plus interrupt latency plus execution overhead" which means the next interrupt will come much sooner than expected.

By reading the current value inside the ISR and adding the timer interval to it, you compensate for interrupt latency. Now the only real-time delay you have is those few lines inside the ISR, which are likely negligible.

Comment: The timer has a 1024 prescaler... I think the CPU can execute hundreds of instructions before it even ticks up by 1.

Comment: @DavidGrayson If the prescaler is set correctly that is. And if there are no other pending interrupts that get handled first. Also never underestimate the awfulness of crappy 8 bitters, why people still design with this dinosaur technology is beyond me. Anyway, this is easy enough to verify, just set a breakpoint inside the ISR and read the value of the timer register from the memory map.

Comment: "why people still design with this dinosaur technology is beyond me" Aren't they generally way simpler, both in terms of hardware and software?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica No that's a weird myth. It used to be that all 8 bitter code was written purely in assembler, around 30 years ago. They are for sure much easier to program in assembler than lets say x86 or PowerPC. Late 90s early 2000s, there was a strong shift to C however. And that's when they turn more complicated to program than for example 32 bitters, because C have all these dysfunctional rules about implicit type promotion and default `int` type all over, completely unsuitable for 8 bitters. They are therefore much harder to program in C than 32 bitters.

Comment: Also many MCU's had hit the limit with the 64kb memory map (most 8 bitters traditionally have 16 bit address bus), so 8 and 16 bitters in the early 2000s era had to invent ways to extend addressing even further. 24 bit addressing and an 8 bit core is a fairly common combination. And also a very awkward and burdensome combination. Add to that extra complexity of Harvard architectures that can't trivially read from data memory. I've mostly dealt with von Neumann 8 bitters but I believe AVR is Harvard.